# how to test extension function without parameter?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

**I have an extension function and it doesn't have a parameter
It formats the date
If the user enters another form, the function will modify it**

This is the format that it should be

```
val DATE_FORMAT = "MMMM d yyyy"
```

this is a function

```
fun String.stringToDate(): Date? {
return SimpleDateFormat(Constant.DATE_FORMAT).parse(this) }
```

How do I test this function ?

Comment: How would you test it if it _did_ have a parameter? This is just the same, except that you pass it as the receiver instead of a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Constant is Class? Or TopClass?
If the function has keep reference, i think that is not problem..
If you want how to test that, So you'll write below code.

```kotlin
expect(Date().format(Constant.DATE_FORMAT)) shouldBe Date().toString.stringToDate()
```